# Terminal opening on startup

Tags: xubuntu

I just upgraded from Xubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. Alongside with some issus with the display (due to a known AMD driver issue), I now have a terminal window opening every time I log in.

How can I understand why this window is popping up?

I'm sorry I cannot give further info but honestly I do not have any idea on what to verify. I checked with systemctl list-units, but no failed services are present

EDIT: this morning the terminal went away. I did 10+ tests yesterday and it was not working, and today it disappeared without any action. I will keep monitoring it, but if anyone has other ideas on how to debug and find out what program is doing this at boot feel free to add info to the answers below

Answer (score 1):

Please check in Settings Manager → *Session and Startup* → *Application Autostart* tab that you do not have an entry for the applications you find starting.

Comment: I checked, and compared the applications with a fresh Xubuntu 20.04 installation. The only differences were the screensaver, the Geoclue demo agent and DWagent (a sort of alternative to teamviewer). I disabled the first two, but with no success (terminal window always appears at startup). I will try to disable DWagent tomorrow, but I don't think it is that one

Answer (score 1):

Logout. When you do uncheck the box that says something to the effect of "Remember session....." or "Save session...." Then log back in and see if the terminal does not open.

Comment: Thank you; however the terminal is not open when I logout/shut down, so it is not remembering the old session

Comment: Ok, have you checked in /home/.config/autostart ??? You'll need to enable view hidden files to see the .config dirrectory.